# How to create a query that shows cases for all status?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a problem in my Django project.
I have some cases like;

| Case Type | Status | Sub Case | Stage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Volleyball | 2020 | finished | win |
| Basketball | 2022 | pending | none |
| Basketball | 2021 | finished | loss |
| Volleyball | 2020 | finished | win |

I want to create a query
for example are there how many cases is **volleyball - 2020 - finished - win**
or are there how many cases is **basketball - 2021 - finished - loss**
There are a lot of cases with different attributes, I have to count them with a dynamical query. Maybe pandas can help me with that but I don't know.
Any idea can help me.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(Case.objects.all().values()))
test = df.groupby(['case_type_id', 'status_id', 'current_stage']).value_counts().reset_index()
```

Comment: If you show your model definition, one could show you a django orm solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is your expected output?

IIUC, is that what you're looking for?

**RESULT**

```
df.groupby(['Case Type','Status','Sub Case']).value_counts().reset_index()
```

OR

```
df.groupby(['Case Type','Status','Sub Case']).value_counts(df['Stage']).reset_index()
```

OR

```
df.assign(cnt=1).groupby(['Case Type','Status','Sub Case','Stage'])['cnt'].sum().reset_index()
```

```
    Case Type   Status  Sub Case    Stage   0
0   Basketball  2021    finished    loss    1
1   Basketball  2022    pending     none    1
2   Volleyball  2020    finished    win     2
```

**Data**

```
data= {'Case Type': ['Volleyball ',   'Basketball ',  'Basketball ',   'Volleyball '],
        'Status': [ 2020,  2022,  2021,  2020],
        'Sub Case': [ 'finished ',  'pending ',  'finished ',  'finished '],
        'Stage': [ 'win',  'none',  'loss',  'win']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
    Case Type   Status  Sub Case    Stage
0   Volleyball  2020    finished    win
1   Basketball  2022    pending     none
2   Basketball  2021    finished    loss
3   Volleyball  2020    finished    win
```

Comment: What is the meaning of df ?

Comment: created the DataFrame from the data set you shared

Comment: Okay, I create a dataframe from my query but there is an error 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts' do you have any idea?

Comment: just added the DF create statement in the solution

Comment: can you post the statement you used for groupby?

Comment: I added the code at the end of my question

Comment: also, post the df output

Comment: what is the version of your pandas?   pandas.__version__

Comment: version: pandas==1.4.2

Comment: I added the alternate solution

Comment: What was the issue? It seems its resolved. and I'm glad